# SurfaceInkCanvas And TagVisualization

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I have a surface application with SurfaceInkCanvas.
Now, I want to do something when the tag is on the canvas (change color for instance).

The problem is, the SurfaceInkCanvas catch the VisualizationAdded event, and draw point on the canvas - instead of Calling the VisualizationAdded event of the TagVisualizer.

If I change the Panel.Zorder of the items, the tag event is catched but I can't draw on the canvas.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the SurfaceInkCanvas as child element of the TagVisualizer:

```
<s:TagVisualizer>
    <s:TagVisualizer.Definitions>
        ... 
    </s:TagVisualizer.Definitions>

    <s:SurfaceInkCanvas />
</s:TagVisualizer>
```